# Not able to view popup to save xls file(in IE7), writing file into servlet response

Tags: java

I am writing a xls file in servlet response. When user request for file using url "http://localhost:8080/AppName" code is working fine in IE7 however when i am trying with IP("http://10.0.1.54:8080/AppName") instead of localhost it dosen't work. I do not gets any popup to save xls file.

The same code with ip in url("http://10.0.1.54:8080/AppName")  works fine in mozilla. 
Ia m using jdk 1.6, tomcat 6 and IE7.

Please suggest me how to overcome from this problem. Thanks for your precious help in advance.

Regards,
Yogi

Comment: does your DNS resolve IP to localhost ??

Comment: I am not sure about your question but does it mean.. i have to map IP with localhost in host file in "C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc" directory ?

Comment: are you able to access rest of the app using IP just this setvlet fails , is it ?

Comment: Yes.. every thing else is working fine..  apart from this..  and i am able to access this using dns and it works fine.. in case of ip only it is not working..

Comment: can you try adding `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=someThing.xls;` header to response

Comment: I have all ready set content type as "application/vnd.ms-excel" and header as "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=xyz.xls" in IE and "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=xyz.xls" for mozilla and others.. but still getting problem with ip only..

Answer (score 0):

Check your **inter**-net vs **intra**-net settings. When you browse using localhost as a host name, IE uses **intra**-net settings. When you use IP, **inter**-net settings are used.

Comment: but how come same thing is working in mozilla... does it not require any internet/intranet settings ?

Comment: What should i add in my code so this settings doesnt affect code and i can access this using ip itself ?

Comment: Mozilla uses different approach to maintain security. IE uses zones. If this is the case, when zone settings block file, its not your fault. Try adding your IP to trusted sites in IE settings.

Comment: I tried same code in IE 6 and it works but in IE 7 and above it is not working .. a also added ip in Tools-> Internet Options-> Security -> Trusted sites...in IE7 but still it is not working.. ... it works if i add ip and map with some name in host file... is there any way to make it possible with ip also..

Answer (score 0):

what `content type` and `content disposition` headers are you returning?

see [this](http://dotanything.wordpress.com/2008/05/30/content-disposition-attachment-vs-inline/)

Comment: I have set content type as "application/vnd.ms-excel" and header as "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=xyz.xls" in IE and "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=xyz.xls" for mozilla and others.